# onProgressChanged() of a SeekBar is called twice

Tags: android, seekbar, preference

I have created a Custom `SeekBarPreference` such that it displays a range of time to be selected from (say `0.2` sec to `2.2` sec). My problem is onProgressChanged() is called twice - once with `progress = 0` and the second time with `progress = "actual value"`. I am storing the value in a `SharedPreference` so that I can use it later in my application. 
Here is my code snippet -

```
@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    LayoutInflater inflator = ((PreferenceActivity) mContext)
            .getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.seek_bar, null);

    mCurrentValue = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext)
            .getFloat(this.getKey(), mDefaultValue);
    ......
    SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    mSeekBar.setMax(20);
    mSeekBar.setProgress((int) ((mCurrentValue - mMinValue)
            / (mMaxValue - mMinValue) * 20)); // 20 = progress bar max value.
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if (progress != 0) {
        mCurrentValue = (float) ((float) progress / 20
                * (mMaxValue - mMinValue) + mMinValue);
    }
    mValueText.setText(Float.toString(mCurrentValue)); 
    /* mValueText is a TextBox where I display my Current Value */
}
```

Here, I have checked the value of progress such that it is `not equal to 0` and hence it avoids the first call. However, the side-effect of this is that I am not able to set anything to `0`. 
 
What can be the work around for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The callback method `onProgressChanged()` has a `boolean` parameter `fromUser`.
Using this **parameter** we can determine if the changes are coming from the **Framework** or are made by the **User** himself.
Thus, an implementation like -

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) { // If the changes are from the User only then accept the
                    // changes
    /* Instead of -> if (progress != 0) { */

        mCurrentValue = (float) ((float) progress / 20
                * (mMaxValue - mMinValue) + mMinValue);
        mCurrentValue *= 10;
        mCurrentValue = Math.round(mCurrentValue);
        mCurrentValue /= 10;
    }

    mValueText.setText(Float.toString(mCurrentValue));
}
```

sets the value of `TextView` only when it is changed by the User.

Comment: fromUser saves my life.

Answer (score 2):

you may use follwing method of OnSeekBarChangeListener.

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
     int progress=seekBar.getProgress();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got another problem today (custom SeekBar and PreferenceFragment). I don't know why, but the code below works only twice: on start touching and on stop:

```
    mTextViewValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_value);
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(@NonNull SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mTextViewValue.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
            }
```

Finally I've got the solution. This one works:

```
    final TextView valueTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_value);
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(@NonNull SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
            }
```

Maybe it helps someone.